# Connect to MariaDB (mysql) and MS Access mdb databases via localhost using unixODBC on Debian?

Tags: debian, mariadb, odbc

I'm a relative linux newby just trying to move my computing from Windows 10 to Debian.  I have been struggling to setup shared dual boot access to my MS Access data bases.  I have found it very hard to get unixODBC to work with MariaDB (or MySQL), and so will share with you what works below, as I answer my own question here.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to connect using ODBC to MariaDB and .mdb databases on Debian 8.6 (Jessie-stable) using the unixODBC manager.

First load a few things:

---

- load package: mariadb-server-10.1   (this works w/ MySQL 5.6)
- load package: unixodbc 2.3.1.3  (unixODBC 2.3.0-4)
- downloaded library from MariaDB.com: mariadb-connector-odbc-2.0.12-ga-linux-x86_64

  - you have to get this direct from MariaDB.com as Debian Jessie does not yet have a package for this.
  - Then: move unpacked libmaodbc.so file to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmaodbc.so
- optionally load package unixodbc-bin 2.3.0-4  (the graphical tools for ODBC management and browsing)

(Note: I have not tried to get the iODBC manager to work, but it appears similar.)

---

unixODBC has two setup files **/etc/odbcinst.ini** and **/etc/odbc.ini**. They can be edited directly, or setup with the GUI tool.  The GUI tool won't setup DNSs if the Driver parameters are not correct.  You'll get something like a parameter error message.

/etc/odbcinst.ini sets up the ODBC driver information (the ODBC driver lib file), and 
/etc/odbc.ini then refers to this driver information to set up the DSN or data server name (the database you will be accessing).

Also there need to be two drivers referred to in /etc/odbcinst.ini, both the main odbc driver (or Driver=.. ) and also the "Setup" driver (or Setup=..).  It appears that the setup driver is a helper with the GUI editor and sets up default parameters (and possibly checks them). But the maria ODBC distro  only gives you the first of these drivers.  I found that using the mysql Setup driver works for the 2nd driver.  Note that drivers have a 'S' in them, e.g. /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so.  You'll find the available drivers listed in synaptic when you select a package, then click properties, and the Installed Files tab.

Here is my /etc/odbcinst.ini file with comments in it.  (Below it is my /etc/odbc.ini file.)

Note the drivers seem to require a full pathname.  I have also included the setup parameters for mdbtools (to access MS Access *.mdb files using ODBC).  Also note that the password and mdb database pathname/filename do not seem to need quotes around them.  They takes spaces and other special characters just fine.  (Except for perhaps "=")?

I have also included commented out options that magically appear in the GUI editor below for future reference.

---

```
[mariadb]
Description=Maria DB
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmaodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so

#The rest of these magically appear in the GUI driver (advanced) setup utility:
#Driver64=
#Setup64=
UsageCount=1
#CPTimeout=
#CPTImeToLive=
#DisableGetFunctions=
#DontDLCLose=
#ExFetchMapping=
#Threading=
#FakeUnicode=
#IconvEncoding=
#Trace=
#TraceFile=


#=================
[mdbtools]
Description=MDBTools Driver
Driver=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so

#The rest of these magicaly appear in the GUI driver (Advanced) setup utility:
#Driver64=
#Setup64=       Get error if include this param for mdbtools
#               (even though it appears in the GUI list as null)
UsageCount=1
#CPTimeout=
#CPTImeToLive=
#DisableGetFunctions=
#DontDLCLose=
#ExFetchMapping=
#Threading=
#FakeUnicode=
#IconvEncoding=
#Trace=
#TraceFile=
#TraceLibrary=
```

---

/etc/odbc.ini (note that the socket needs to be changed below to point to the default socket the MariaDB exposes in Debian):

```
[mariadb-bb]
#Description    - defaults to $Driver
Description=Bigbase

#Driver: Required. The name of the MariaDB ODBC Driver. Must be always {MariaDB ODBC 1.0 Driver}
#       the 1.0 comment above is possibly outdated
Driver=mariadb

#Server: name or IP of the MariaDB database server. Aliases: Servername - defaults to null
Server=localhost

#Database: default database. Aliases: DB - defaults to 'test'
Database=somedatabase

#Port: TCP/IP Port of the database server - defaults to null
Port=3306

#When using Server=localhost we will be connecting thru the socket exposed by mariadb.
#You can find this socket file location&name in /etc/mysql/my.ini  - defaults to null if missing
Socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

#Option: For MySQL Connector/ODBC compatibility. Aliases: Options - defaults to null
#(not sure what this is used for?)
#Option=

#Stmt - defaults to null  (not sure what this is used for?)
#Stmt=

#---Optional----------------:
#DSN: Name of the DSN  (not sure what this is used for?)
#DSN=

#User: user name for database authentication. Aliases: UID,
User=root

#Password: password for database authentication. Aliases: PWD
Password=bigdog


#=========
[PW]
Description=mdbtools
#Driver needs to point to a driver in /etc/odbcinst.ini
Driver=mdbtools
Database=/home/user/Shared/Documents/test.mdb
```

You can then test your ODBC with the following two tools:

```
/usr/bin/isql   - Utility to submit SQL queries to a data source.
/usr/bin/iusql  - Unicode version of isql.
```

Note: You can either pipe a sql command as standard input into these, e.g. `echo "select * from tableA" | isql` or it will prompt for sql lines with `sql>` when run.  See `man isql`.  If you give isql options like for example your password, it will override the password in your /etc/odbc.ini file.

Hope this helps someone else.

---

Finally here are crib notes of what files are in what related packages:

```
* unixodbc:

     unixodbc-bin       2.3.0-4     - Graphical tools for ODBC management and browsing
    /usr/bin/ODBCManageDataSourcesQ4    - 1&2 ODBC Administrator
    /usr/bin/ODBCCreateDataSourceQ4     - 2 create Data Source Name wizard

    These are mentioned in the README file but are not in the package:
      /usr/bin/odbcinstQ4               - a Qt based installer library/plugin (don't have)
      /usr/bin/ODBCTestQ4               - an interactive test program (don't have)
      /usr/bin/ODBCDataManagerQ4        - Data Manager (not done)

    /usr/share/doc/unixodbc-bin/README

    /usr/share/menu/unixodbc-bin        - some sort of menu data file

    Notes: Only works if both main driver and setup drivers exist.


   unixodbc     2.3.1-3         - Basic ODBC tools
    /usr/bin/isql                       - Utility to submit SQL queries to a data source.
    /usr/bin/iusql                          - Unicode version of isql.
        notes: Can either pipe standard input into them, e.g. echo "select * from m" | isql ...
        or it will prompt for the sql> when run.

    /usr/lib/odbc                       - the lib

    /usr/share/doc/unixodbc/README

    /usr/share/man/man1/isql.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/iusql.1.gz


     libodbc1           2.3.1-3 ODBC library for Unix
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.1      -> libodbc.so.2
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2      -> libodbc.so.2.0.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbc.so.2.0.0      - lib odbc

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.1        -> libodbccr.so.2
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.2        -> libodbccr.so.2.0.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbccr.so.2.0.0        - lib odbc cr  ?? cr, but I think like .rc (setup?)

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libnn.so         - lib nn

    /usr/share/lintian/overrides/libodbc1               - ?



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* myodbc:
   libmyodbc        5.1.10-3    the MySQL ODBC driver
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so         - the mysql driver

    /usr/share/libmyodbc/odbcinst.ini                   - table of drivers

    /usr/share/doc/libmyodbc/examples/odbc.ini          - Example table of data sources
    /usr/share/doc/libmyodbc/README.Debian              - note about not building a -dev package


-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* odbcinst:
   libodbcinstq4-1  2.3.0-4 Qt-based ODBC configuration library
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinstQ4.so.1        -> libodbcinstQ4.so.1.1.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinstQ4.so.1.1.1

   odbcinst     2.3.1-3 Helper program for accessing odbc ini files
    /etc/odbc.ini       - Setup table for list of DSN's.  Each one points to a driver in /etc/odbcinst.ini
        notes: don't need to quote special characters in file names like spaces or parens.

    /usr/bin/odbcinst   - - command line tool for batch ODBC configuration
        run /usr/bin/odbinst or 'man odbcinst' for usage, e.g. syntax and options

    /usr/share/man/man1/odbcinst.1.gz

    odbcinst1debian2    2.3.1-3 Support library  for accessing odbc ini files
    /etc/ODBCDataSources            - etc

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1      -> libodbcinst.so.2
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2      -> libodbcinst.so.2.0.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.2.0.0      - inst


    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libesoobS.so     - setup driver
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmimerS.so     - setup driver

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcdrvcfg1S.so   - setup driver - drvcfg1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcdrvcfg2S.so   - setup driver - drvcfg2
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcminiS.so  - setup driver - mini
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcmyS.so        - setup driver - my (mysql)
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcnnS.so        - setup driver - nn
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbcpsqlS.so  - setup driver - psql
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libodbctxtS.so       - setup driver - txt

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/liboplodbcS.so       - setup driver - opl odbc
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/liboraodbcS.so       - setup driver - ora odbc

j   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libsapdbS.so     - setup driver - sap db

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libtdsS.so           - setup driver - tds


    /usr/share/lintian/overrides/odbcinst1debian2       - inst1 debian2



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* MDB:
   odbc-mdbtools        0.7.1-2 MDB tools ODBC driver
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbc.so        - driver
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmdbodbcW.so   - ?


   mdbtools         0.7.1-2 JET / MS Access database (MDB) tools
    /etc/bash_completion.d/mdbtools - bash command completion extension

    /usr/bin/mdb-array              - Export data in an MDB database table to a C array
    /usr/bin/mdb-export             - Export data in an MDB database table to CSV format
    /usr/bin/mdb-header         - dump  the  names and types of the tables and columns
    /usr/bin/mdb-hexdump            - Hexdump utility from MDB Tools
    /usr/bin/mdb-parsecsv           - Convert CSV table dump into C file
    /usr/bin/mdb-prop               - Get properties list from MDB database
    /usr/bin/mdb-schema         - produces  DDL  (data definition language) output
    /usr/bin/mdb-sql                - allows querying MDB database using a limited SQL subset
    /usr/bin/mdb-tables             - Get listing of tables in an MDB database
    /usr/bin/mdb-ver                - Return the format of a given MDB database.

    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-array.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-export.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-header.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-hexdump.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-parsecsv.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-prop.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-schema.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-sql.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-tables.1.gz
    /usr/share/man/man1/mdb-ver.1.gz


    mdbtools-doc
    /usr/share/doc-base/mdbtools-faq
    /usr/share/doc-base/mdbtools-install

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/HACKING.gz
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/NEWS.gz
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/README.gz
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/TODO
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/faq.html

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/index.html - A Guide to Installing and Configuring MDB Tools

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/a304.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/book1.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/c29.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/c42.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/c98.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/c180.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/c202.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/c260.htm

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/f19.htm

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x53.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x86.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x90.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x94.htm

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x196.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x199.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x231.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x244.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x251.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x276.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x289.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x314.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x324.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x328.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x334.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x370.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x375.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x379.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x383.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x386.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x389.htm
    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/html/x394.htm

    /usr/share/doc/mdbtools-doc/install.sgml.gz


  mdbtools-gmdb         0.7.1-2 - JET / MS Access database (MDB) file viewer
    /etc/bash_completion.d/mdbtools-gmdb    - bash command completion extension

    /usr/bin/gmdb2                          - THE application (graphical interface)

    /usr/share/applications/mdbtools-gmdb.desktop   - setup?

    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-debug.glade      - graphical
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-export.glade
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-prefs.glade
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-props.glade
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-schema.glade
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-sql.glade
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb-tabledef.glade
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/gmdb.glade

    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/code.xpm      - images
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/debug.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/form_big.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/forms.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/logo.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/macro_big.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/macros.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/module_big.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/pk.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/query.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/query_big.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/report_big.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/reports.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/table.xpm
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/table_big.xpm
    /usr/share/pixmaps/gmdb2.xpm

    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/stock_export-16.png
    /usr/share/gmdb/glade/stock_export.png
    /usr/share/gnome/help/gmdb/C/figures/gmdb2_sql_window.png
    /usr/share/gnome/help/gmdb/C/figures/gmdb2_window.png
    /usr/share/gnome/help/gmdb/C/gmdb.xml
    /usr/share/gnome/help/gmdb/C/legal.xml

    /usr/share/man/man1/gmdb2.1.gz  - GNOME UI for MDB Tools

    /usr/share/menu/mdbtools-gmdb



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* mariadb-connect-engine=10.1
    /etc/mysql/conf.d/connect.cnf

    /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/ha_connect.so


* mariadb-connector-odbc-2.0.12-ga-linux-x86_64
    /lib/libmaodbc.so   -- moved this to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmaodbc.so
    /share/doc/mariadb_connector_odbc/README



-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* iodbc:
  libiodbc2     3.52.9-2    iODBC Driver Manager
  iodbc         3.52.9-2    GTK+ config frontend for the iODBC Driver Manager
    /usr/bin/iodbcadm-gtk   - graphical ODBC administration program using the GTK+ widget set.
    /usr/bin/iodbctest      - iODBC Demonstration programs

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrvproxy.so.2      - a link?   lib drv proxy so
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdrvproxy.so.2.1.20

    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbcadm.so.2      - a link?   lib iodb adm
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libiodbcadm.so.2.1.20

    /usr/share/doc/iodbc/README.Debian  - not much help

    /usr/share/lintian/overrides/iodbc

    /usr/share/man/man1/iodbcadm-gtk.1.gz       - graphical ODBC administration program
    /usr/share/man/man1/iodbctest.1.gz      - iODBC Demonstration programsq
```